# Sylius 1.0 with elasticsearch

Tags: sylius

I recently upgrade sylius from 0.18 to 1.0@dev and I lost the elasticsearch support since SyliusSearchBundle is not included in core anymore.
I have no search nor facetting anymore.

What I tried :

- I have added manually SyliusSearchBundle
- I made a few fixes in configuration
- I launched sylius:search:index command

My products are fully indexed. But now that taxon pages are handled as Resources, the queries are made directly on the database, not elasticsearch.

What are the steps required to query elasticsearch for taxon page ?
On the documentation page for [SyliusResourceBundle](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusResourceBundle/) I can see that
Elasticsearch is not yet supported :

> So far we support:
>
> - Doctrine ORM
> - Doctrine MongoDB ODM
> - Doctrine PHPCR ODM
> - InMemory (soon)
> - ElasticSearch (maybe)

Does it means I have to write a custom controller for taxon page ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You do not want the storage driver to be elasticsearch for you resources, but rather let it function as a secondary faster storage that you use in some cases.

I assume you are using `FOSElasticaBundle` so you have a nice API of working with your elasticsearch indexes.

For example when you are on a search page, you will want to have your own `SearchController` that uses the elasticsearch services to do the work. Then you can simply use the aggregations/facets in your template. See the `FOSElasticaBundle` [docs](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md) for more information about this.

Comment: Ok, so what I understand is that I have to write custom controllers for search page and taxon page. Thanks